# Should I really use NoSQL?

Tags: mongodb, performance, couchdb, scalability, nosql

I have some reports which combines data from 3 different servers creates json and shows it to users . When there are thousands of records it impossible to process it over web and it times out . I am now queuing users request and generating a json file and sedning a link so when user opens link I just show data instead of any processing .

I came across NoSql recently. In my particular case Will there be any benefits of using NoSql over storing data to a file apart from able to run queries on it ?

Comment: There are too many factors here that we don't know. Are you working in a team? If so, does that team have more experience with SQL vs NoSQL solutions? Will they be willing to learn if you choose the one they are less familiar with? You can try to answer these questions, but there will be countless more. Therefore, I don't really see how anyone can answer this question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have thousands of records aggregated results, you should be able to process them with SQL or NoSQL for almost any use case.

NoSQL isn't a magic bullet that just makes SQL faster, it is a different kind of data storage solution that has its own strengths and weaknesses.

Whether a flat file, SQL or NoSQL to aggregate a few thousand records of data is best depends very strongly on your comfort zone and on the query requirements.  From a performance perspective, all will work well on a data set of that size.  If you find yourself writing more than trivial logic to manage your current file, use either SQL or NoSQL based on your level of comfort with each.

Comment: Oh I see... you are talking about temporary storage for the aggregated data.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating reports, chances are the answer is "no."  SQL is basically a transactional and reporting environment, and you have to understand you are giving up both of these to a significant extent when going to NoSQL solutions as primary storage.  This is also why many of the most impressive NoSQL deployments use these engines as adjuncts to, rather than replacements for, the traditional RDBMS.

My suggestion in this case is you want to look at using more SQL *and* connecting your servers together so that you can run this as a single SQL query.  I don't know what RDBMS you are using so I can't offer specifics but on PostgreSQL you can do foreign data wrappers and use these to query data from the other three servers.  Yes, you can hit non-PostgreSQL servers through these.....

My guess is that your problem if it is only a few thousand rows is that you are doing in client programming what could be more efficient on the database side.

Comment: One can certainly use NoSQL for reporting.  See Map/Reduce, e.g. http://indoos.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/bi-with-mapreduce/

Comment: Yes, but that's using data transformation on input.  If your reporting requirements change and you need a new report tomorrow over a billion records, you are SOL.

Comment: If your reporting requirements change and you're using SQL with inappropriate indices or need to include data not in your star schema, you're in for a world of hurt too.  Anyhow the OP is talking about a few thousand records.